# Was the supposed action in The Running Man filmed live or not?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-running-man

In the movie [The Running Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093894/?ref_=nv_sr_4) Fireball's death is captured on the show but moments earlier, when Amber discovered that the three "pardoned" prisoners were dead, apparently weren't filmed even though the show is broadcast live.

How is this possible?

Comment: Presumably because the cameras of the show were concerned with the action that the audience was there to see. There were just no cameras in the area where Amber found the bodies (also it's possible - given the secretive nature of their deaths - that the cameramen would be instructed to keep away from that area)

Comment: I think fireball was killed in the vicinity of the bodies

Comment: ...by the magic broadcasting power of cheesy 80s Arnie flicks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was the premise of the in-movie show that the "winners" would receive pardons...

> ```
>  Now Ben Richards could have gone to prison and paid the penalty but 
>  instead he volunteered for The Running Man...and have a chance at our 
>  fabulous przses like a trial by jury, suspended sentence, maybe even a 
>  full pardon like our previous winners, Wittman, Price and Hadad. You 
>  remember them, Wittman, Price and Hadad, there they are, and at this 
>  very moment they're basking in the beautiful Maui sun, their debt to 
>  society paid in full.
> ```
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.horrorlair.com/scripts/runningman.txt)</sup>

...but *in reality* they were killed (presumably by Fireball) and their escapes faked.

Recall that Ben and Amber were replaced by digital body doubles and "killed" for the audience even though they had escpaed.

The point is that the show is a **sham**. There is no *actual* escape, the totalitatian state which runs the show wouldn't allow it.

Recall the exchange after Ben & Amber's "deaths"..

> ```
> Amber
>  What's wrong? You should be happy, we're officially dead. We can go 
>  anywhere, do anything. 
>
> Ben
>   No, don't you understand it. He'll never let us out of here alive, they 
>   can't afford it. They'll get the police, the army and hunt us down like 
>   dogs, off camera of course.
> ```

So, yes it was filmed "live" **until** it was inconvenient for the state and then  what was happening was either *not shown* or a *complete fake*.

Comment: how could they possibly know that amber would enter that chamber so that they could omit or change the footage

Comment: That area was never under surveillance.